# Let bibtex declare and use acronyms in reference section

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, acronyms

Suppose I have a two (or, in fact, an arbitrary number of) bibtex entries as follows:

> @inproceeding{one,author = {Paul Elk}, title = {Moo}, series = {The Original Oak Likes Our Natural Ginseng}, ...}
>
> @inproceeding{one,author = {Darma Shian}, title = {Waf}, series = {The Original Oak Likes Our Natural Ginseng}, ...}

As you may guess, the series name takes a lot of room in the references section.

I know there is a way (but I can't find it any more) to have latex/bibtex work so that the end result looks like:

> [1] Paul Elk. Moo. In ..., volume 1 of The Original Oak Likes Our Natural Ginseng (henceforth 'TOOLONG'), 1942.
> [2] Darma Shian, Waf, In ..., volume 2 of TOOLONG, 1955.

Ideally, that would work for any number of entries, whatever order they appear in.
It is ok for me to choose the acronym, no need to infer it computationally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bib file write

```
series={\toolong}
```

and in your document say

```
\newcommand{\toolong}{The Original Oak Likes Our Natural Ginseng
  (henceforth `TOOLONG')\gdef\toolong{TOOLONG}}
```

In the `.bbl` file you'll have `\toolong` in all the entries; the first one will be written fully and then it will redefine `\toolong`.

This can be done completely in the `.bib` file with a `@preamble` entry:

```
@preamble{"\newcommand{\toolong}{The Original Oak Likes Our Natural Ginseng (henceforth `TOOLONG')\gdef\toolong{TOOLONG}}"
```